Concerns after Submitting Abstracts to a Special Issue
I am a PhD student in social sciences, currently based in the UK. I came across a CfA from a special issue published by an esteemed US university Press last month, which was quite relate with the philosophical base of my research. I submitted an abstract on 15th of March and received the reply immediately from ediors saying that they had received my abstract and they would be in touch soon.
In the CfA notification we were informed:

"Authors invited to submit full length papers will be notified by April"

Does it mean I have to wait till the end of the April for the result of whether my abstract is accepted or not?
Should I write an follow-up email asking about the reviewing process?
And whether will I be informed if being rejected?
Another concern is-- the word limit of abstract should be under 500 words, and my submitted abstract was less than 200 words, which seems quite far away from 500. Will this impact the acceptance/rejection of a CfA?
This is the first time I submitting an abstract for a special issue. Really with I could get a satisfied result.

I would interpret that to mean end of April if not mid-May depending on number of submissions.
